# $(\cdot)^r$ is continuous function for $r \in \mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}$

Tags: calculus, limits, measure-theory, continuity

I'm trying to prove this proposition, and getting nowhere: $(\cdot)^a$ is continuous function $\mathbb{R}_{>0} \to \mathbb{R}$ for $a \in \mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}$.

I'm also having difficulty manipulating the function $(\cdot)^a$; the only definition I know of this is through the exponential function, which is not ideal for proving things like this. Would anyone have a nice proof of the above proposition from first principles? I tend to get confused when the answers are compact, so please consider writing things out please!

Comment: Hint: carefully examine the definition of $(\cdot)^a$. How does it look when $a \in \mathbb N , \mathbb Z ,\mathbb Q ,\mathbb R?$

Comment: Actually it's not continuous $\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$, but rather continuous on $\mathbb R^+-\{0\}$.

Comment: Can someone enlighten me on what this notation means.

Comment: @DerekLuna The function $x \mapsto x^r$. Albert, this function is (in general) not defined over $\mathbb{R}$, but only over $\mathbb{R}_{> 0}$.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe (and Surb) good point! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A shortcut: $x^a=e^{a\ln x}$ so it s enough to show that $x\to e^x$ is continuous.

By definition, $e^x=\underset{n\to \infty}\lim\left(1+\frac xn\right)^n$ and it is easy to show that this sequence is increasing (apply Bernoulli's inequality). Then, $e^x\ge \left(1+\frac xn\right)^n\ge  1+x.$ From this we get also, $e^{-x}\ge 1-x$ so $e^x\le \frac{1}{1-x}$ if $x<1.$ Hence, $1+x\le e^x\le \frac{1}{1-x}$ if $0<x<1.$

Using the above, as soon as $|x-x_0|<1$, we get

$1+(x-x_0)\le e^{x-x_0}\le \frac{1}{1-(x-x_0)}\Rightarrow x-x_0\le e^{x-x_0}-1 \le \frac{1}{1-(x-x_0)}-1$

so $|e^x-e^{x_0}|=e^{x_0}|e^{x-x_0}-1|\to 0$ as $x\to x_0.$